# Delphi C++ Indy UDP Server BytesToString does not receive correct string?

Tags: delphi, udp, c++builder, indy

I am trying to receive UDP packets from a TUIO multi-simulator. But some of the data is missing.

https://www.tuio.org/?specification

```cpp
void __fastcall TMain::UDPServerUDPRead(TIdUDPListenerThread *AThread, const TIdBytes AData,
    TIdSocketHandle *ABinding)
{
    UDPData->Lines->Add(BytesToString(AData));

    for (int i = 0; i < AData.Length; i++)
        UDPData->Lines->Add((char)AData[i]);
}
```

When I use `BytesToString()`, I only get the word `"#bundle"` as a string, but when use the second loop I get this:

#
b
u
n
d
l
e

/
t
u
i
o
/
2
D
c
u
r
,
s
i
a
l
i
v
e
4
/
t
u
i
o
/
2
D
c
u
r
,
s
i
f
f
f
f
f
s
e
t
?

ﾎ
9
>
￻
ￚ

/
t
u
i
o
/
2
D
c
u
r
,
s
i
f
s
e
q
#
b
u
n
d
l
e

/
t
u
i
o
/
2
D
o
b
j
,
s
a
l
i
v
e

/
t
u
i
o
/
2
D
o
b
j
,
s
i
f
s
e
q
#
b
u
n
d
l
e

/
t
u
i
o
/
2
D
c
u
r
,
s
a
l
i
v
e

/
t
u
i
o
/
2
D
c
u
r
,
s
i
f
s
e
q

With each character on a separate line, of course.

So, how can I get the correct data when I don't know the encoding? I am lost here and need really help.

Also, how can I send a similar bundle data with `TIdUDPClient`?

Comment: So, what encoding is the data sent in? And why are you processing it one byte at a time? And how do you know that the entire package has arrived?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "*how do you know that the entire package has arrived?*" - UDP is message-oriented, not stream-oriented like TCP.  `TIdUDPServer` receives whole messages only, not partial messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UDP data you showed is mostly binary data with some textual elements inside of it.  As such, you should not be converting the *entire* `AData` to a single string with `BytesToString()`, since it is not entirely text to begin with (well, you could, using `BytesToStringRaw()`, or `BytesToString()` with `IndyTextEncoding_8bit()` as the encoding, but it wouldn't really help you much to do so).

You need to break up the data into its individual components, per the [protocol specificiation](https://www.tuio.org/?specification) that you linked to (which in turn is based on the [Open Sound Control](http://opensoundcontrol.org/specification) protocol). Only then can you process the components as needed.  That means you need to loop through the `AData` byte-for-byte, parsing each byte in context, per the protocol.

For example (this is, by far, not a complete implementation, but it should give you an idea of what kind of logic is involved):

```cpp
struct OSCArgument
{
    char Type;
    Variant Data;
}

struct OSCBundleElement
{
    virtual ~OSCBundleElement() {}
};

struct OSCMessage : OSCBundleElement
{
    String AddressPattern;
    DynamicArray<OSCArgument> Arguments;
};

struct OSCBundle : OSCBundleElement
{
    TDateTime TimeTag;
    DynamicArray<OSCBundleElement*> Elements;

    ~OSCBundle()
    {
        int len = Elements.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
            delete Elements[i];
    }
};

int32_t readInt32(const TIdBytes &Bytes, int &offset)
{
    uint32_t ret = GStack->NetworkToHost(BytesToUInt32(Bytes, offset));
    offet += 4;
    return reinterpret_cast<int32_t&>(ret);
}

TDateTime readOSCTimeTag(const TIdBytes &Bytes, int &offset)
{
    int32_t secondsSinceEpoch = readInt32(Bytes, offset); // since January 1 1900 00:00:00
    int32_t fractionalSeconds = readInt32(Bytes, offset); // precision of about 200 picoseconds
    // TODO: convert seconds to TDateTime...
    TDateTime ret = ...;
    return ret;
}

float readFloat32(const TIdBytes &Bytes, int &offset)
{
    uint32_t ret = BytesToUInt32(Bytes, offset);
    offet += 4;
    return reinterpret_cast<float&>(ret);
}

String readOSCString(const TIdBytes &Bytes, int &offset)
{
    int found = ByteIndex(0x00, Bytes, offset);
    if (found == -1) throw ...; // error!
    int len = found - offset;
    String ret = BytesToString(Bytes, offset, len, IndyTextEncoding_ASCII());
    len = ((len + 3) & ~3)); // round up to even multiple of 32 bits
    offset += len;
    return ret;
}

TIdBytes readOSCBlob(const TIdBytes &Bytes, int &offset)
{
    int32_t size = readInt32(Bytes, offset);
    TIdBytes ret;
    ret.Length = size;
    CopyTIdBytes(Bytes, offset, ret, 0, size);
    size = ((size + 3) & ~3)); // round up to even multiple of 32 bits
    offset += size;
    return ret;
}

OSCMessage* readOSCMessage(const TIdBytes &Bytes, int &offset);
OSCBundle* readOSCBundle(const TIdBytes &Bytes, int &offset);

OSCBundleElement* readOSCBundleElement(const TIdBytes &Bytes, int &offset)
{
    TIdBytes data = readOSCBlob(Bytes, offset);
    int dataOffset = 0;

    switch (data[0])
    {
        case '/': return readOSCMessage(data, dataOffset); 
        case '#': return readOSCBundle(data, dataOffset);
    }

    throw ...; // unknown data!
}

Variant readOSCArgumentData(char ArgType, const TIdBytes &Bytes, int &offset)
{
    switch (ArgType)
    {
        case 'i': return readInt32(Bytes, offset);
        case 'f': return readFloat32(Bytes, offset);
        case 's': return readOSCString(Bytes, offset);
        case 'b': return readOSCBlob(Bytes, offset);
        // other types as needed ...
    }

    throw ...; // unknown data!
}

OSCMessage* readOSCMessage(const TIdBytes &Bytes, int &offset)
{
    OSCMessage* ret = new OSCMessage;
    try
    {
        ret->AddressPattern = readOSCString(Bytes, offset);

        String ArgumentTypes = readOSCString(Bytes, offset);
        if (ArgumentTypes[1] != ',') throw ...; // error!

        for (int i = 2; i <= ret->ArgumentTypes.Length(); ++i)
        {
            OSCArgument arg;
            arg.Type = ArgumentTypes[i];
            arg.Data = readOSCArgumentData(arg.Type, Bytes, offset);

            ret.Arguments.Length = ret.Arguments.Length + 1;
            ret.Arguments[ret.Arguments.High] = arg;
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        delete ret;
        throw;
    }

    return ret;
}

OSCBundle* readOSCBundle(const TIdBytes &Bytes, int &offset)
{
    if (readOSCString(Bytes, offset) != "#bundle")
        throw ...; // error!

    OSCBundle *ret = new OSCBundle;
    try
    {
        ret->TimeTag = readOSCTimeTag(Bytes, offset);

        int len = Bytes.Length;
        while (offset < len)
        {
            OSCBundleElement *element = readOSCBundleElement(Bytes, offset);
            try
            {
                ret->Elements.Length = ret->Elements.Length + 1;
                ret->Elements[ret->Elements.High] = element;
            }
            catch (...)
            {
                delete element;
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        delete ret;
        throw;
    }

    return ret;
}

void __fastcall TMain::UDPServerUDPRead(TIdUDPListenerThread *AThread, const TIdBytes AData,
    TIdSocketHandle *ABinding)
{
    int offset = 0;

    if (AData[0] == '/')
    {
        OSCMessage *msg = readOSCMessage(AData, offset);
        // process msg as needed...
        delete msg;
    }
    else if (AData[0] == '#')
    {
        OSCBundle *bundle = readOSCBundle(AData, offset); 
        // process bundle as needed...
        delete bundle;
    }
    else
    {
        // unknown data!
    }
}
```